# Не запускается виндовс в GRUB

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-7, grub

Уже создавал подобную тему, но продвинулся в решении проблемы вперед, по-этому считаю лучше будет открыть новую тему.
На ноут с виндой поставил ubuntu второй системой, после чего не запускался grub, grub починил, но вот разделы на диске определяются неправильно.

```
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1126399   1124352   549M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1126400 548001399 546875000 260,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       548001792 665188351 117186560  55,9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       665188352 937701375 272513024   130G 83 Linux
```

В grub винда определяется в директории /dev/sda1, хотя на самом деле она находится на /dev/sda2 как изменить это
Также по моей задумке: /dev/sda3 - раздел с linux, a /dev/sda4 - домашний раздел linux.
Но кажется что я что-то напортачил при установке ubuntu.
Когда в груб пытаюсь зайти в винду меня кидает обратно в груб и всё.
Как это всё дело исправить ?
Хочу подчеркнуть, что всё это находится на одном жестком диске и я имею доступ к файлам windows с linux.

Comment: Разделы у вас определены правильно. `/dev/sda1` - это recovery, загрузочный раздел для восстановления Windows. `/dev/sda2` - это диск C. Вы можете загрузить Linux? Если да, что возвращает команда `sudo os-prober`?

Comment: /dev/sda1:Windows 7:Windows:chain

Comment: на маленьком разделе живет загрузчик, граб правильно указывает на него.

Comment: Хорошо, но когда в загрузчике выбираю Windows 7(on /dev/sda1) черный экран и меня выкидывает обратно в граб, как это исправить?

Comment: сначала восстановить загрузчик https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0 windows. потом заново восстановить загрузчик grub